# How can I fix that my HTML website does not scroll on mobile devices?

Tags: html, css, web, mobile, scroll

I have a HTML, CSS, JS website and on my computer it works perfect but on my Razer Phone with chrome it does not scroll vertically. The website is german but the text doesn´t matter.

If i zoom in it scrolls until the next navigator, then it stops. If i switch in mobile chrome to desktop site, it scrolls perfect, but in mobile mode it doesn´t.

Sry for my english
Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of your

> animate.css line 11:

```
html, body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Try to remove it.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I removed it, but the problem is still there.

Comment: Again thanks for the answer, but it looks like I solved it. At animate.css i added overflow: auto;